# How to load each line of a file into a different textbox

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I need some help with my app.
I'm a beginner on programming with C# and UWP.
I have 3 textboxes where I save the data on each line in a text file.
I use the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder to do it.

But how do I load each line back into the textboxes?

I have done it with a file to each textbox, but that's a lot of files later on when I need to do it again with some other things in the app.

Hope it's understandable !

Here is the code that I've done for saving.

```
    private async void OpretBilFlyoutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filenameBilmarke = "BilMarke.txt";
        string bilMarke = BilMarke.Text;
        string bilModel = BilModel.Text;
        string kmTaller = KmTaller.Text;

            StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile fileBilMarke = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filenameBilmarke, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(fileBilMarke, bilMarke + "\r\n" + bilModel + "\r\n" + kmTaller);
   }
```

Comment: Can your text boxes contain newlines or return characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

First Install [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) Package from Nuget

Then create a Base Class with the data that you want to save.

```
public class MyData
{
    public string BilMarke { get; set; }
    public string BilModel { get; set; }
    public string KmTaller { get; set; }
}
```

For saving the data, You need to change the method to below.

```
private async void OpretBilFlyoutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string filenameBilmarke = "BilMarke.txt";

    MyData data = new MyData();
    data.BilMarke = BilMarke.Text;
    data.BilModel = BilModel.Text;
    data.KmTaller = KmTaller.Text;

    string finaldata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile fileBilMarke = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filenameBilmarke, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(fileBilMarke, finaldata);
}
```

If you notice I am serializing the Object `MyData` to Json and saving it directly.

Now to retrieve, you can just Deserialize the content from Text File

```
MyData textdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(finaldata);
```

And you can Assign it back to textboxes like below.

```
BilMarke.Text = textdata.BilMarke;
BilModel.Text = textdata.BilModel;
KmTaller.Text = textdata.KmTaller;
```

Good Luck.

Comment: @TheisTN, you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper left of the answer.

Comment: Got it :) ! @DourHighArch